# Having two models on a ListView in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have set a ListView query which works fine. I now want to add a star ratings to the thumbnail so that each car has its own customer star rating within the thumbnail.

My present Listview is as such:

```
class CarListView(FilterMixin, ListView):
    model = Car     
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    filter_class = CarFilter
```

I am getting an error saying:

> 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Now I think it is because I have not added the star ratings model which is an app on its own onto the ListView. Any idea how I can add the star ratings model here? The star ratings library I am using is django-star-ratings.

Comment: That sounds like you have the Car or CarFilter variable set to a string rather than a model. Its difficult to tell with a minimal amount of code you have given.

Comment: More like something is undefined in the template, and that gets passed in as an empty string to the template tag.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback with your question. The one line error message is not enough to show where the problem is.